# Convertir milisegundos a hora/minuto/segundos en Android

Tags: android

Alguien me podría ver un ejemplo de la clase CountDownTimer para un formato de hora/minuto/segundos, gracias.

he intentado con esto pero no resulta

```
contador.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
```

> El problema es que MILLISECONDS lo marca en rojo. solo me da la opcion
>   de MILLISECOND pero, despues de esto no me aparece toHours.

trabajo con la version 5.1 de android.

Comment: Que no te resulta? Te lanza algun error? Elabora mejor tu pregunta para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: @Einer he arreglado la pregunta, gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios problemitas, el primero sin duda es definir el correcto import que debe ser :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Esto para usar la clase y su constante:

```
 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
```

El segundo es que esta incorrectamente calculadas las horas, falta el argumento necesario. El formato que agrego debe ser el correcto para el formato que deseas:

```
String FORMAT = "%02d/%02d/%02d";
String  myTime =  String.format(FORMAT,
                //Hours
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished) -                        TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished)),
                //Minutes
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                //Seconds
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
```

Otro método que es más sencillo para obtener el formato deseado sería este:

```
Date date = new Date(millisUntilFinished);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH/mm/ss");
String myTime = formatter.format(date );
```

Para ambas opciones, como ejemplo una hora definida como `05:25:25 PM` se obtendría:

```
17/25/25
```

Comment: Deseo hace un contador atrás, como un cronometro, que muestre los horas/minutos/segundos. y al cambiar el paquete me marca en rojo

Comment: Debes usar : import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; ya lo realizaste? @Ash

Comment: Si, ha funcionado, disculpa la demora y gracias !

Comment: Excelente!  saludos! @Ash

Answer (score 2):

La clase que buscas es [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). Probablemente estas utilizando la clase `TimeUnit` del paquete `android.icu.util` que no contiene `MILLISECONDS`.

Cambia:

```
import android.icu.util.TimeUnit;
```

Por:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Comment: probare y te comento !